# Inline edited catch response in javascript

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, inline-editor

When making any changes in inline edit and save. The controller which is called on the save button is passing some content to the ajax call.

I want need to get that data in javascript how can i do it.

Edited
The inline edit feature of magento 2 allow to edit the record displayed in the listing.
Now once we changed the input of column and click save it go to a controller and save changes. 
A controller can send some response with content. I am sending some response from the controller i want to catch that content.

In normal Ajax we call the controller and controller process that reqrest and send some content back. This content is catched by ajax call.

How can i do this with magento's 2 default inline save?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Changes made please check.